# How discriminator loss generated?

Tags: loss-function, gan

The images generated by generator has **no labels**, then how do Discriminator loss is generated **on the basis of classification of generator generated images.**

Answer (score 0):

We already know that the images from the generator are fake and those from our training set are real. So, we assign them labels manually, real images as $0$ and fake ones as $1$, which gives us labelled data. Check the definition of loss function in any implementation of a GAN and you'll find that we assign the labels ourselves. For example, take a look [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/dcgan#define_the_loss_and_optimizers).

Answer (score 0):

The Discriminator is just a binary classifier. You don't need labeled data as all the inputs are of same class.

So, Discriminator is considered as perfect classifier if it outputs `TRUE` for input real image and `FALSE` for generated image.

Discriminator loss is made up of two components:

```
Discriminator Real Loss: Prediction of real image as fake image
Discriminator Fake Loss: Prediction of fake image as real image
Discriminator Loss = Discriminator Real Loss + Discriminator Fake Loss
```